# add class on scroll in bootstrap tabing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

i need a small help for add a class on scroll in bootstrap tabbing carousal.
so here is my page url

when i click on any point from tabing like 1,2,3.. active class is adding on tabing on same that is perfect i use this is script

```
    $('#myCarousel').bind('mousewheel', function(e){$(this).carousel('next');});

$('.tab li').on('click', function(){
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

it is working perfect as class is adding on li.active but i also want .active class on current tab when i scroll in tab container. i have added scroll code and working perfect but need class to add in .tab li when i scroll

here is HTML code as well

```
<div class="tab">
<div class="container-tab">
<ul class="list-inline nav">
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"> <a href="#">
<div class="round-tab-num"> 1 </div>
<p>Working Smart <small>not harder</small> </p>
</a> </li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"> <a href="#">
<div class="round-tab-num"> 2 </div>
<p>Working Smart <small>not harder</small> </p>
</a> </li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"> <a href="#">
<div class="round-tab-num"> 3 </div>
<p>Working Smart <small>not harder</small> </p>
</a> </li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3"> <a href="#">
<div class="round-tab-num"> 4 </div>
<p>Working Smart <small>not harder</small></p>
</a> </li>
<li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4"> <a href="#">
<div class="round-tab-num"> 5 </div>
<p>Working Smart <small>not harder</small></p>
</a> </li>
</ul>
<!--The main div for carousel-->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel horizantal slide" data-interval="false"> 

<!-- Sliding images statring here -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
<div class="item active">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h3>test1</h3>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h3>test2</h3>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h3>test3</h3>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h3>test4</h3>
</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
<div class="carousel-caption">
<h3>test5</h3>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Next / Previous controls here -->

<div> </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

this code is also added

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('#myCarousel').carousel({
        interval:   4000
    });

    var clickEvent = false;
    $('#myCarousel').on('click', '.container-tab .nav a', function() {
            clickEvent = true;
            $('.container-tab .nav li').removeClass('active');
            $(this).parent().addClass('active');        
    }).on('slid.bs.carousel', function(e) {
        if(!clickEvent) {
            var count = $('.container-tab .nav').children().length -1;
            var current = $('.container-tab .nav li.active');
            current.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
            var id = parseInt(current.data('slide-to'));
            if(count == id) {
                $('.container-tab .nav li').first().addClass('active'); 
            }
        }
        clickEvent = false;
    });
});
```

Comment: when you will scroll active class is jumping to next li and if you scroll back class ig going forward please check this

Answer (score 0):

change your code as below simply remove class from currently active **li** and add active class to next li as below

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
    $(this).carousel('next');
    var $currentlyactive =$('li.active');
    $currentlyactive.removeClass('active');
    $currentlyactive.next().addClass('active');
});
```

**Updated**

```
$(document).ready(function() {      
   $('.carousel').carousel('pause');
});
$('#myCarousel').bind('mousewheel', function(e){$(this).carousel('next');});

$('.tab li').on('click', function(){
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

this is the code in your html page remove this all carousel related code has been done in **custom.js**..

Comment: check now url not working perfect moving too fast Thanks

Comment: Ohh it'll not work remove this i'll give you another solution and remove from link so i can find a solution on this link

Comment: as i have been gone through from console it seems like you have a **custom.js** where you have applied same thing for this..
Remove all the javascript code from html page related to **carousel**

Comment: do not remove **custom.js**

Comment: which one i need to remove **custom.js* or above code from html page please tell me right now i have remover bottom code and custom.js is there

Comment: You have commented this line <!--<script src="js/custom.js"></script>
-->
please uncomment this

Comment: Okk that's great done now wait i will give you a code which needs to add in custom.js

Comment: scrolling is not working now also click on 4point then back to 2 number then check check active class is on 5 not in 2

Comment: did you get any solution ??